# Laravel - validate only digits with fixed length and required space

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am writing a regular expression to validate a zip code, where it should have exactly a length of 6 characters, the first 3 characters are digits, the last 2 also, but the character 4 should be a space.
Here some examples:

- "123456" is not valid because no space in character 4.
- "123 45" is valid.
- "123 4" is not valid because the length is 5 instead of 6.

  Here what I wrote:

  /^[0-9 ]{6,6}$/

It works fine, just in this code above, the space is not required (but it should be).

Comment: Why not use the logic  you describe? `/^\d{3} \d{2}$/`?

Comment: you could write a comment instead of just down voting !!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how exactly? let me try it

Comment: seems to work, thanks alot

Comment: Note if you want to make some clean validation, instead of manually validating it you could use [Laravel 5.1 Custom validations rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules) and use it in a validation on your controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\d{3} \d{2}$/
```

It matches 3 digits, space, 2 digits strings. See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2R3Rdv/1).

**Details**

- `^` - [start of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits ([`\d`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) matches an ASCII digit in PHP regex by default, same as `[0-9]`)
- - space
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `$` - [end of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Note that `{6,6}` [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) is the same as `{6}`.

Answer (score 0):

You were close but you missed some things.

If you changed your regex to this, it should have worked.

```
^[0-9]{3}\s[0-9]{2}$
```

Or you could also use

`^\d{3}\s\d{2}$`

Note that when you say `{6,6}`, it means the preceding expression must occur between m and n times. You could just give it as `{6}`, although your regex is wrong, it's just  something to know.

Hope it helps :)